# Chrome browser not displaying UTF-8 characters

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

I've searched stackoverflow and other websites, but I couldn't find anything useful to my case, so I decided to create a new question hoping that someone has an answer to my problem.

My problem is with Chrome browser only, I'm creating a simple bootstrap website located here: http://www.farahfa.com/rikkidesigns

On IE and Firefox the breadcrumbs looks fine, but on Chrome it doesn't show the Unicode characters (home, and '>') it only displays boxes.

Is there anyway to make it display the correct characters just like in Firefox and IE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't a browser problem, it's a font problem (though different browsers will have different font settings which will affect how characters display).

U+1F3E0 House Building  is a recent addition to Unicode (6.0) and is relatively poorly supported in fonts. The most commonly-installed font that supports it is, on Windows, Segoe UI Symbol, so you can give Chrome a clue by adding the CSS rule `font-family: "Segoe UI Symbol"` to the icon.

At the time of writing, I personally wouldn't rely on U+1F3E0 because too many devices won't display anything useful. Consider an image, SVG icon or embedded font.

Comment: Do you know what system font in mac that has the U+1F3E0? Just so the website can be also compatible with apple products too..

Comment: `Apple Color Emoji` from 10.7, but you may not want the colour rendering.